# Google Docs Prevent Download

Tags: google-sheets, google-drive, google-docs, google-workspace-for-business, g-suite-business

I using GSuite product for my company, however we are working with outsource team. That guy will working (eg. editing) with several GDocs, GSheet file. I wanted to disable download feature on GDocs and GSheet but they can still editing the file online.

I have try this 
[image]

This works for disable download, but my employee cannot editing that document.
How they can still editing the document via browser and cannot download that file?

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, Google's permissions settings are simply not that granular. In their eyes, the choices are

- Can view
- Can comment [and view]
- Can edit [and comment and view]

and those choices can be offered to individual accounts by email address, to anyone with the link, or publicly on the web. Google is a huge company, but if their choices are causing a problem for you, they encourage users to choose Report a Problem from the Help menu, and explain it to them.

On a higher level though, if an account can edit a given document, then they can do whatever they want with it—overwrite its contents, change values, or; naturally, they can make their own copy, whether by copy-paste, File→Make a copy, or by download—so with a good faith hope that your situation gets resolved, I must say that I think you'll have to solve the problem with, say… conversations, rather than checkboxes. Good luck.